# Best Practices for controlling access to form fields

Tags: asp.net

I have a classic 3-tier ASP.Net 3.5 web application with forms that display business objects and allow them to be edited. Controls on the form correspond to a property of the underlying business object. The user will have read/write, readonly, or no access to the various controls depending on his/her role. Very conventional stuff.

My question is: what is the object-oriented best practice for coding this? Is there anything more elegant than wrapping each control in a test for the user's role and setting its Visible and Enabled properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work properly, I have found that access levels should be in this increasing order:
NONE, VIEW, REQUIRED, EDIT.

Note that REQUIRED is NOT the top level as you may think it would be since EDIT (both populate & de-populate permission) is a greater privilege than REQUIRED (populate-only permission).

The enum would look like this:

```
/** NO permissions.
 *     Presentation: "hidden"
 *     Database: "no access"
 */
NONE(0),

/** VIEW permissions.
 *     Presentation: "read-only"
 *     Database: "read access"
 */
VIEW(1),

/** VIEW and POPULATE permissions.
 *     Presentation: "required/highlighted"
 *     Database: "non-null"
 */
REQUIRED(2),

/** VIEW, POPULATE, and DEPOPULATE permissions.
 *     Presentation: "editable"
 *     Database: "nullable"
 */
EDIT(3);
```

From the bottom layer (database constraints), create a map of fields-to-access.  This map then gets updated (further restrained) at the next layer up (business rules + user permissions).  Finally, the top layer (presentation rules) can then further restrain the map again if desired.

Important: The map must be wrapped so that it only allows access to be *decreased* with any subsequent update.  Updates which attempt to increase access should just be ignored without triggering any error.  This is because it should act like a voting system on what the access should look like.  In essence, the subsequent layering of access levels as mentioned above can happen in any order since it will result in an access-level low-water-mark for each field once all layers have voted.

Ramifications:

1) The presentation layer CAN hide a field (set access to NONE) for a database-specified read-only (VIEW) field.

2) The presentation layer CANNOT display a field when the business rules say that the user does not have at least VIEW access.

3) The presentation layer CANNOT move a field's access up to "editable" (nullable) if the database says it's only "required" (non-nullable).

Note: The presentation layer should be made (custom display tags) to render the fields by reading the access map without the need for any "if" statements.

The same access map that is used for setting up the display can also be using during the submit validations.   A generic validator can be written to read any form and its access map to ensure that all the rules have been followed.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to drive this off of data, trust me. You'll need a lot of tables to do it right, but it is so worth it in the end. Having to crack open code and edit a bunch of if-statements every time the business wants to change permissions is a killer.

You'll want a table for your main high-level types, things you probably already have business object clases for. Then a table for each status of them. Then a table for the fields of these classes. Then a table for user roles (admin, guest, etc.) Finally a table for the permissions themselves. This table will have columns for business class, status, field, user role, and then what permission they have. For permissions I would go with one field and use an enum: Hidden, ReadOnly, Editable, and Required. Required implies Editable. Anything but Hidden implies Visible. Finally put a Priority column on this table to control which permission is used when more than one might apply.

You fill out this table with various combinations of class, status, field, role, and permission. If a value is null then it applies to all possible values. So you don't need a trillion rows to cover all your bases. For example, 99% of the time, Guest users are read-only users. So you can put a single entry in the table with only the Guest role specified, everything else is null, and set it's Priority nice and high, and set the permission to Read Only. Now for all classes, all statuses, all fields, if the user is a Guest, they will have Read Only permission.

I added status to your list of concerns because in my experience, business all the time wants to constrain things by an object's status. So maybe users can edit an item's name while it is in Draft status, for example, but once it is in Posted status, the name is no longer editable. That is really common in my experience.

You'd want to bring this table into memory and store it in the app's cache, because it's not going to change very often, if ever, unless you do a whole new version.

Now the above is going to handle 90% of your needs, I suspect.

One area that will have to be handled in code, unless you want to get really fancy, is the cases where a user's permission is determined in part by the *value* of fields *in the object* itself. So say you have a Project class, which has a Project Manager class. Now the Percent Complete field of the class is basically read-only for everybody, *except* the Project Manager. How are you going to handle that? You'll need to provide a way to incorporate specific instances of a class into the decision making process. I do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

I have often found that this is really the only real easy and understandable way to do it, as your interface needs to modify based on the information and level of editing that they can complete.

I do find typically though that depending on the needs, you can interject the "cannot edit" information by passing role information to the business level if you have plans to move to different presentation levels. but this adds complexity, and if you are only building for one interface it would most likely be overkill

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct for doing this in a more OO way would be to handle your roles and their implementations for this purpose (control permissions read/write/etc) is to use the abstract factory pattern for your roles.  I will be happy to explain the ins and outs of what I am talking about if you'd like but there are probably 900 examples on the web.  Here is [one link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120402110237/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/SanjayU/archive/2008/12/15/another-abstract-factory-explanation.aspx) (disclaimer: it's my blog but it does happen to talk to using abstract factory for roles specifically)

Using something like this you could then use a number of methods to display the correct controls for each of your business object properties with the correct attributes (read/write/hidden/displayed/etc).

Answer (score 0):

For the website menus we can have different menus based on users role by using the Sitemaps. For controls like Buttons we will have to hide them using their Visible property. I think a good idea will be to create a server control (Button) and expose the Role property. This will hide the Button if the user is not in the correct role.