# ASP.Net membership store group concept

Tags: asp.net-membership

This question has been asked before in this forum. I like to get more input regarding this.

Are there any pre-existing solutions out there which would extend the built in SQL Membership Provider & Sql Role Providers in .NET with the concept of Group Membership.

Right now the Roles relationship looks like

Users ====> UserRoles <=====Roles

I'd like to extend that to look like

Users ====> UserGroups <==== Groups ====> GroupRoles <==== Roles.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Membership provider doesn't support that feature.

However, you can override Membership Provider and Role Provider to extend that feature.

Look at this SO answer - [Custom Membership Provider and MembershipUser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6007759/296861)

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider
http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/11/CreateCustomMembershipProviderASPNETWebsiteSecurity.aspx
http://www.shiningstar.net/aspnet_articles/customprovider/CustomProvider.aspx
http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/0/page/3
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomMembershipProviders.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx