# Uploading & Video Voting asp.net system

Tags: asp.net, video, upload, system, codeplex

Anyone knows an asp.net voting video sistem?

I have searched over codeplex but havent found a thing.

any ideas?
regards

Answer (score 1):

That is not hard to do, follow me on the draft

- open an account on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) (They host your .NET project in AWS) using your GIT or Hg repository, superb service!
- in that account you can have MS SQL, mySQL, or a bunch of NoSQL databases, chose your winner
- open an account on AWS for their S3 hosting so you can add the videos safely
- create a new MVC 3 Project using Razor and HTML5
- Add some nuget packages like Elmha, Glimpse, etc
- Access your database using for example the marvelous [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and create 4 tables, `TblUsers`, `TblRoles`, `TblVideos`, `tblRating`

Then add as properties

```
[TblUsers]
    user_id, role_id, email, encodedPwd, created_at, validate_at

[TblRoles]
    role_id, name

[TblVideos]
    video_id, uploaded_by, uploaded_at, filename

[TblRating]
    ratting_id, video_id, user_id, ratted_at
```

- Use a custom Membership and Roles provider just [like I show as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0/5702000#5702000) so you are handling the log in and permissions correctly
- Now, let a user upload a Video where you will add to your AWS S3 Bucket using their [AWS .NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) and all you have to do for a file to go to S3 automatically with the correct permissions is copy/paste [my code in this support question](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/749-handling-uploading-files)
- And let users voted in a video

simple and easy :o)