# How to - Facebook Connect with existing user table

Tags: asp.net, facebook, registration

I have a registration-login system on my own website yet I want to add Facebook Connect too. I have some required parts of my user table as:

Username
Password
Email

The first thing that came to my mind is,  setting userId as username, userId@facebook.com as email and setting the password to null and check if a record exists with these details in my user table. If not insert a new user with these details, if exists return that user details.

Is this a good design? How should I connect facebook connect to my website?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take this into a more deep ASP.NET, and start an MVC project

then use the Microsoft [Facebook API SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation) to play around with the API, it's very easy and because they are using the new `dynamic` type, now that Facebook changed the Open Graph, it will continue to work great as well.

in your login page, add a facebook login button and ask for permissions, for example:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email" size="medium">
    redirect-uri="http://yourdomain.com/FBLogin/"
    Subscribe using Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

in your FBLogin controller, login the user using the FB credentials, if the user uses your normal form, use the normal login

If you create a custom MemberShip Provider, you can easily use that for both accesses... I write a simple start to a custom [Membership provider here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0/5702000#5702000)

Comment: I'm already 90% the project and want to implement just facebook connect. Why would I start a MVC project for this? :|

Comment: it's a good way to start in the MVC world, as I'm sure it will be much simpler to maintain ... though the **Membership provider** is not only for MVC, it's for any .NET web project and the Facbeook API can be use is Webforms as well. You should read that I said **I would suggest**, the rest of the answer does not depend on it, it was only a suggestion, my answer is still the way to go in my opinion