# ASP MVC 3 Basic Register / Login / Logout on a different table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-authentication

I have seen the default 'Account' Model and Controller which comes default with a standard MVC3 Application, how ever, as I have generated my Database first.

I already have designed my own 'Users' table, which I'd like a simple Registration / Log in / Log out to be implemented.

Are there are good tutorials showing me how to do this or any advice from yourselves? Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Duplicate question I think.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Create your class derived from the abstract class `MembershipProvider`

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

}
```

More at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

Do the same for `RoleProvider` if you need it.

```
public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{

}
```

More at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

Implement only the methods you will use and that's all. Start with `ValidateUser()` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser.aspx)

Don't forget to point your provider, that is in this case `MyMembershipProvider` to web.config in  `<system.web>    <membership>      <providers>` section.

Don't complicated it as in almost every tutorial/blog post out there is doing, it's a simple task.

UPDATE:

In the RoleProvider you only need to implement

```
public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            return RoleRepository.GetAllRoles();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            return RoleRepository.GetRolesForUser(username);
        }

public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {  
            return RoleRepository.IsUserInRole(username, roleName);
        }
```

In the MembershipProvider you only need to implement

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return MembershipRepository.IsUserValid(username,password);
        }
```

You could always use your own `ValidateUser()` method regardless of the method in the MembershipProvider.

Comment: Many thanks for this structured response! 

Could you provide an insight as to what I'd need to fill out in order to have a simple register/log in/log out on another table please?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your custom Membership provider:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: I see the two tutorials above are MVC 2, do you have MVC 3 tutorials available?

Comment: why would you need a tutorial for MVC3, it's the same as you're implementing methods from MembershipProvider and RoleProvider ?

Comment: It's in the same way in MVC 2 and 3.