# Good ASP.NET MVC projects to look at for authentication and cookie management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, so I was looking out for open-source projects either on Codeplex/Github/Bitbucket which I can look at and understand how to implement authentication, authorization and implement remember me, cookie management and stuff.

Can some one please guide me to any good projects that has a nice implementation on authentication and cookie management.

Comment: You can try nopCommerce, or maybe even the Music Store sample site, though I know that is a pretty simple starter-level example and may be a bit too basic.

Comment: check this information http://innovacallframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15946#295013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very many open source projects which implement authentication, authorization and implement remember me, cookie management. They are different from simple to complex portal systems like Orchard cms.

- For beginning it would be nice to explore microsoft music tore tutorial and part in which explained authentification and authorization http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7, here is a source of it http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/,
- Besides forums engines is a web application which always use authorization and authentification, you can download one of mvc forums http://mvcforum.codeplex.com/ or http://nearforums.codeplex.com/
- Any cms use administration part, and you can look how to implement authorization and authentification on AtomicCms https://github.com/yaplex/AtomicCms
- And besides you can dig source of huge portal system like Orchard http://orchard.codeplex.com/, which implement authorization features too.

Answer (score 1):

you can find projects mainly on codeplex -> http://themvcforum.codeplex.com/ , nerddinner or apps listed at http://www.asp.net/downloads open source free applications in asp.net . on the other hand if you are new to asp.net mvc I believe that you must read http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx . during many years microsoft proposed asp.net membership system but sometimes was frustrating to work with - stored profiles using blob columns. the future in galloway words is simplemembership and display the possibility to use your own table schema to store user information, includes oauth and more.
more important some books have details about it eg: Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 (Wrox Professional Guides) [

Answer (score 0):

The samples available on blogs etc that i have bookmarked previously are:

[C# MVC3 Custom Membership Provider, Custom Roles, Razor Entity Framework & LINQ](http://custommemberprovider.codeplex.com/)

[Altairis Web Security](http://altairiswebsecurity.codeplex.com/)

[How can I install asp.net membership schema in my existing database?](http://tipsaspdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-can-i-install-aspnet-membership-in.html)

[Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server (VB)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb)

[Implementing your own RoleProvider and MembershipProvider in MVC 3](http://brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx)

[SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

[Code First EF 4.1 with the Altairis Membership/Role Provider](http://www.culbertsonexchange.com/wp/?p=120)

[Custom Role Provider for MVC](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC)

But have a look at my previous answer here [ASP MVC 3 Basic Register / Login / Logout on a different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066025/asp-mvc-3-basic-register-login-logout-on-a-different-table/10067020#10067020)
because using MembershipProvider with your own DB is simple to implement and it works great.