# How to dynamically generate controls in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In asp.net, you can use asp:Repeater for dynamically generating controls.

for example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rpt">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Textbox runat="server"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then you can get loop through the items on the server side:

```
foreach(var items in rpt.Items)
{
}
```

And in MVC, you can do something like this:

```
@foreach(var item in model)
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>item.searchCriteria);
}
```

But there is a problem:

I would like to generate textboxes when ever user clicks add more textbox button:

[image]

If I use foreach in MVC, then I won't be able to fetch the user input on the controller, also, I don't have a model to loop through.

And the final desired output will be:

After the user clicks the "Add more textbox" button, a new textbox will be append to the bottom, and after the user clicks the search button, the text inside the textbox will be generated into a query string, something like this:

View:

```
 <input name="searchCriteria" type="text" class="form-control" />
 <input name="searchCriteria" type="text" class="form-control" />
 <input name="searchCriteria" type="text" class="form-control" />
 <input name="searchCriteria" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Search()
        {
            string queryString = Request.RawUrl;
            //parse the querystring here
            return View(NumberOfVisitorsReport);
        }
```

And the query string generated will be:

```
www.website.com/?searchCriteria=a&searchCriteria=b&searchCriteria=c
```

So are there any alternative way to achieve this in MVC?

Edit:

I've took a look at some post on "How to generate controls dynamically in MVC"

For example

[Control creation based on model value in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624270/control-creation-based-on-model-value-in-mvc4)

He is generating controls based on value in database, if I implement this to my website, the controls will lose value on each post back.

Comment: You can use JavaScript...that's generally the best approach when you want to make something happen on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use jquery.

This article can help for solve to problem.

[Dynamic Form in Asp.net MVC & jquery](http://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/13/dynamic-form-in-asp-net-mvc-jquery/)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to move away from "postback" and look to adding text boxes dynamically in the browser using jQuery or a similar framework.  If you either name the new text boxes carefully or do the submit as an AJAX post of a JSON object, you can harvest all the values from all the added controls.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use **For loop** insead of ForEach. Then use the **index** to Create new Textbox controls, this way when you submit the form, index of newly created textbox will be submited, you can even BIND it to a model if the data type of your model is **LIST**.

Example:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contributor.Count(); i++)
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Contributor[i].Id)

  }
```

now you know the value/index of **"i"**, use that to populate new controls.