# Integrating SimpleMembershipProvider in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I'm having a hard time implementing (or integrating) ASP.NET SimpleMembershipProvider. I already have the database tables from a previous version of the application and I don't want to create new user tables, roles, etc... I want to use the existing tables (already mapped with entity framework) so the users in the database can log in to the future application. Here's what I did:
Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Auth" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
```

Global.asax

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyConnectionString", "tblCreds", "IdCred", "Login", false); 
// I put false in the end because I don't want it to create new tables
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserCreds creds)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserBLL bll = new UserBLL();
                BaseUser authUser = bll.Authenticate(creds.Login, creds.Password);
                if (authUser != null)
                {
                    WebSecurity.Login(creds.Login, creds.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error";
            return View();
        }
```

And I'm getting this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'webpages_Membership'
```

Thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing that exception as SimpleMembershipProvider internally uses these table names. Unfortunately they are not overridable (until last i used it).

The design goal with SMP was to provide an out of the box working model of membership with its own table schema. You can configure user table name and add more column but not everything.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360126/simplemembership-with-custom-database-schema-in-asp-net-mvc-4) question for more information.

Comment: Looks Like I'm going to do the whole work myself :( Thank you