# User registration and authentication in asp .net

Tags: .net, authentication

I have created table "users" in database. I have to register user and authenticate him. I want to use asp .net create wizard and login control but i don't know how to register user in my own database using these controls. i don't want to create ASPNETDB.MDF.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom membership provider to achieve this.

Similar question: [Custom MembershipProvider in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0)

Another sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

MSDN docs on membership provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx

hope this helps!