# Password in Simple Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SimpleMembership Provider. I customized some fields on UserProfile Table. I have some queries over there.

1. Is it possible to add password field in UserProfile table itself
   rather than storing seperately in webpages_Membership.
2. Also in another project,without using any of the membership the users and roles tables are implemented. Are they can be mapped to simple
   membership now?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, if you're going to use ASP.NET features, you need to use them as they are presented to you.

What you can do is use **your own Membership Provider** and then you can have anything you want in your users table.

Just [follow up **my answer** on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702000/28004), it is very simple to create your own membership provider and it gives you the ability to use exactly what you need and how you need it.

Comment: Thanks, so do i need to implement my own membership provider for the second issue too ?

Comment: Yes, that goes with your second point as well, if you create your own Membership and Roles Provider, you can just use whatever you have and still benefit from .NET Membership and Roles Features.