# Membership modification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a query regarding Asp.net membership.
Actually i have a requirement to have 2 security question and answers but asp.net membership only provide with the facility oh 1 security question.

is it possible to modify this functionality. I have tried doing it by changing things here and there but nothing comes with the appropriate solution.

Kindly suggest any other way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use your own custom MembershipProvider. A quick search comes up with:

[Custom Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0)

There should be many more examples if you do a google search, but this should give you a starting point.