# Cross platform Membership Provider ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to work a way to allow for ASP.NET membership to be configured once in the web.config, but be able to be configured against both SQL Azure and also Postgres.

I know there are the Microsoft.AspNet.Providers and also the NauckIT providers, but I really want to just use a single provider that will allow both.

Firstly, is there a membership provider that would allow both Postgres and SQL/SQLAzure?

Alternatively, is there a way to extend the Microsoft.AspNet.Providers to allow it use Postgres for storage? and for the matter SQLite?

Basically, I want to continue to use Membership Class as it's riddled through the codebase.

Any links would be helpful.

Comment: Basically, you want to read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701673/custom-membershipprovider-in-net-4-0/5702000#5702000) :) Then create your database interface and load the correct source to read and update the membership. Can't be easier ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asp.net 4.5, there is the new "Identity 2.0", and an extension that allows you to use NHibernate (or various other dbs) as the backing store for it.

Check out:

https://github.com/milesibastos/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity

There is also a nuget package.